# set opacity when element reaches the bottom edge

Tags: css, angular

I am working on animation using angular.  I have the following animation after 1s

```
{opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(100%)', offset: 1.0}
```

This will set the opacity of the element that I am animating to 0 when it reaches 100% to the bottom.  However, when the element moves to the bottom, a scrollbar appears in the body to accomodate this transition.  Is there a way I can prevent the scrollbar from showing or set the opactity to 0 once the bottom part of the element touches the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the main body or div to

```
overflow: hidden;
```

so the scroll wouldn't appear.

Comment: i can't do that because the body is a grid list, it's supposed to have a scroll bar when there are many items on it.  When I delete an item, i want it to animate downwards but prevent scrollbar from showing if initially the no. of items in the grid list does not exceed the body's length